# Disable vagrant default ssh behaviour

Tags: ssh, vagrant

Is there a way to disable the default behavior of vagrant to ssh when doing 'vagrant up'?  From their doc. I don't see that mentioned anywhere? https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set a provisioner in your Vagrantfile (a script to stop the sshd service). This will lock access. You use the gui?

Comment: I see, the provisioner I am using is actually non-local, specifically vsphere via a plugin - https://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere so not sure how that'd work.

Comment: That is a provider, not a provisioner.